# How to extract force when the center of mass of molecules is put in the box in GROMACS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics

To extract the force as in the title I used the `gmx trjconv` command like below.

```
gmx trjconv -f alad.trr -s alad.tpr -n alad.ndx -pbc mol -novel -force -o alad.gro
```

However, the force was not extracted in `alad.gro` file.
Of course, I got the coordinates and the force at equal intervals when getting the `alad.trr` file.

Another way, I used `gmx traj` command to get force.

```
gmx traj -f alad.trr -s alad.tpr -n alad.ndx -pbc -mol -ox coordi.xvg -of force.xvg
```

However, the force obtained from `force.xvg` didn't look like the value I wanted.

So, how do I get the force of molecules put in a single periodic box?

Comment: Could you include a figure showing force.xvg, and a better description of what it is exactly that you would like to measure, and why you think the output is not correct.

Comment: However, I'm still wondering why coordinates of alad gro and coori.xvg are not same.

Comment: I solved the problem. As gmx trjconv -pbc mol option only make molecules translate, the cooridinates obtained from alad.gro can correspond to forces obtained from gmx traj -f alad.trr -s alad.tpr -n alad.ndx -of force-dump.xvg(same results using gmx dump command). However, coordinates of coordi.xvg doesn't match with alad.gro . Also I couldn't trust force.xvg. whether the data is correct is tested by my own work ouput. So it's hard to say simple..

Comment: There is a proposal for a Stack Exchange site for [Materials Modeling](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MWI2OThkMGQyYjliYTEyYmVhNGMwZTJhZThkNGIzMTgwOTU4ODcxOTFjNjEyZjQ1OGE5MDkxZWUxYzlkMTljZEzcd783JnrUkRk1grEB1SEQHGSvWrXk1GVNc0FS4dcW0) which is currently in the commitment phase. There are a lot of experts currently there and questions like these would get more activity there. It would be great if you could help building the site by committing to the proposal.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. As gmx trjconv -pbc mol option only make molecules translate, the cooridinates obtained from alad.gro can correspond to forces obtained from gmx traj -f alad.trr -s alad.tpr -n alad.ndx -of force-dump.xvg.